# How to "save" current Layout on android studio?

Tags: java, android

I'm building an application where can I save notes and attach some images to them, the idea is when I click the imageView It will expand and appear in the middle of the screen and when I click it again it will go back to its original state.

For this I am creating a new Constraint layout and "inflating it" when user clicks the image, but on the second I want to go back to my previous Layout.

Is there a better way to accomplish this with my approach?

```
//Setting image from gallery

        placeholder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (isLoaded){

                        //Image gets bigger on click 


                    if(isImageFitToScreen){

                        isImageFitToScreen = false;
                        placeholder.getLayoutParams().height = originalHeight * 2;
                        placeholder.getLayoutParams().width = originalWidth * 2;

                        //Need to center the image


                        ConstraintLayout myLayout = new ConstraintLayout(getApplicationContext());
                        myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

                        ((ViewGroup)placeholder.getParent()).removeView(placeholder);

                        myLayout.addView(placeholder);
                        setContentView(myLayout);

                        ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();

                        set.constrainHeight(placeholder.getId(),
                                ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        set.constrainWidth(placeholder.getId(),
                                ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT);

                        set.connect(placeholder.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT,
                                ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0);
                        set.connect(placeholder.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT,
                                ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 0);
                        set.connect(placeholder.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP,
                                ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, 0);
                        set.connect(placeholder.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
                                ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);

                        set.applyTo(myLayout);



                        view.requestLayout();




                    } else {

// Here I want to get to my previous layout

                        placeholder.getLayoutParams().height = originalHeight;
                        placeholder.getLayoutParams().width = originalWidth;

                        isImageFitToScreen=true;
                        view.requestLayout();

                    }
```

Comment: It's usually rather cumbersome to reset an `Activity`'s entire layout with `setContentView()` after the initial call in `onCreate()`. It's often easier to add any new `View`s to an existing `ViewGroup` in the original layout, then remove them when needed. You wouldn't have to try to "save" the previous one, then. There might be other options, too, that would be suitable for your design; e.g., displaying your image in a `Dialog` or `PopupWindow`.

Comment: That's true tho, I have done it by setting the visibility of another imageView i've placed in the middle of the screen to visible and it does the job, but doesn't seem to be the best way... About reseting the entire layout I totally agree thats a bad practice. I will see the popupwindow